# How to return nothing or skip a certain element in a list if it is not odd

Tags: python, syntax

I am very new to Python and I'm having trouble converting my thoughts into syntax.

This is the problem I was given:

Given a 1 by n array a, write a function odd(a) to return a new array containing elements whose index is an odd number.

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1])

odd(a) = array([3, 2, 3, 1])
```

and this is what I have so far:

```
def odd(a):
    return ['' if x%2==0 else x for x in a]
```

This, however, returns:

```
[1, 3, '', '', 5, 3, '', 1]
```

How do I simply just skip that element?

Comment: Move the conditional to the end of the list comprehension, where it filters instead of mapping: `for x in a if x % 2 == 0`.

Comment: Also `x` isn't index of your element but element itself.

Comment: The key thing to note is that an "if else" comes before "for" in list comprehension, but a pure "if" goes at the end. Just takes getting used to the syntax.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good point. It can be easier to read and understand the comprehension syntax by thinking about how you would write the expression for the set in mathematics. Suddenly the notation with the if at the end becomes intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to iterate through element and it's index simultaneously and with condition `index % 2` to extract all odd position values:

```
import numpy as np

def odd(a):
    return [x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i % 2]

a = np.array([1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1])
print(odd(a))

# [3, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you! What does % mean?

Comment: @MimiChung, it is mod operator, basically finding remainder of the division operation. If there is a remainder when a number is divided by 2, then the number is sure an odd number.

Answer (score 3):

Use slice and step (see reference here: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)):

```
def odd(a):
  return a[1::2]

#=> [3 2 3 1]
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing this at first, but I wasn't sure about how to even write the increment! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

odd = lambda a: [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if i%2]

a = np.array([1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1])
print(odd(a)) # -> [3, 2, 3, 1]
```